# How to update statsmodels to 0.13.0.dev0 version (to use OrderedModel module)?

Tags: logistic-regression, statsmodels

**What I was trying to do?**

I was trying to analyze data using ordinal logistic regression. For that, I tried to import `OrderedModel` from `statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model` as suggested by [this doc](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/ordinal_regression.html).

**Then, what is the problem?**

After execution of the above mentioned import statement, I got the following error.

```
No module named 'statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model'
```

**How did I try to solve the problem?**

First of all, I checked the `statsmodels` version, I am using. I find that I am using the latest version (0.12.1), available in Anaconda. From [this doc](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model.OrderedModel.html), I perceive that I will need to use 0.13.0.dev0 version to get the `OrderedModel` module, as in v0.12.1, there is no folder/file named `OrderedModel`. However, I do not find any way to update the `statsmodels` to 0.13.0.dev0 version.

**Then, my question**

How can I update `statsmodels` to 0.13.0.dev0 version so that I can use `OrderedModel` module?

**Note**: I know that in Python, there are [some other ways](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168262/ordinal-logistic-regression-in-python#188713) to do ordinal logit regression. However, I want to use `statsmodels` due to it's nice summary of analysis.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can install a recent build from the [nightly wheel repository](https://anaconda.org/scipy-wheels-nightly/statsmodels) hosted on Anaconda.org.

Run `pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/scipy-wheels-nightly/simple statsmodels`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you will need to compile from the GitHub.  See prior related question here:

[How to update to the developer version of statsmodels using Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57868744/how-to-update-to-the-developer-version-of-statsmodels-using-conda)